# Asynchronous Availability Group Secondary Verify Up To Date with Primary Before Backup

Tags: backup, high-availability, data-synchronization

I was wondering if there was a way to include a verification step before a backup on a secondary replica under asynchronous commit mode in availability groups to verify that the secondary replica is up to date with the primary. We intend to run backups on secondary replicas only to keep load off of our primary. However, we do not want to sacrifice performance by using synchronous commit so we must stick with asynchronous.

Current setup is a FCI as the primary, and 2 additional instances setup as secondary replicas. All configured as asynchronous commit mode. One secondary is read-intent only, another is a readable secondary.

Is there any solution that you know of that could essentially give us the best of both worlds?

Comment: How often do you take full backups and how big are the databases and how many databases you have ?

Comment: It will be a full nightly backup. It will be about 3 databases, the biggest one is about 100GB